# I have a problem with compiling my script with PySide6

Tags: python-3.x

When i'm trying to compile my app i getting a problem with PySide6.QtSVG
How can i fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Application.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "Panel\gui\qt_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtSvgWidgets import *
ImportError: could not import module 'PySide6.QtSvg'
```

Comment: What command made this happen?

Comment: It's invoked when i trying to open my app after compiling in auto-py-to-exe

Comment: To fix this in the UI, open the advanced tab and find the --hidden-import input. Simply paste the 'PySide6.QtSvg' into this input and then repackage. If the original error is still appearing, you have done this incorrectly.

Comment: Thx, it's really helped me :)